# Non-greedy regex for watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I want to get rid of the first occurrence of 'my' in the following string:

`my Marsha Tammy`

My current regex setup is greedy I think:

`.sub(/my/,"")`

Which gets rid of all instances. Data will look like this:

```
my Bill Port
my Samy Gonzalez
my Ulm Germany
```

Only want first occurrence of 'my' gone.

Comment: `sub` only replaces the first occurrence (see the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub)). If it's not doing what you expect, you should provide an example input and the unexpected output you are getting.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Selenium/Watir related specifically. If you are interested in doing something other than parsing resulting text with ruby & regex, please update your question to make that part more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `.sub(/^my/,"")`

This is a working example:

https://regex101.com/r/tD2jI2/1

EDIT: Or even better - `.sub(/^my /,"")` to get rid of the trailing space

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ruby docs for [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub):

> Returns a copy of `str` with the *first* occurrence of pattern replaced by the second argument.

So, you should be in the clear in terms of it only replacing the first instance of your regexp. If you wanted it to replace all instances then you need to use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).